# Azure Cognitive Services - Batch Transcription API responds with error message "The recording URI is invalid."

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

**Steps Followed:**

1. I created a speech services instance in West US.
2. I have the right headers`(Content-Type and Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key)`
3. I make a POST request to https://westus.cris.ai/api/speechtotext/v2.0/transcriptions/ with below request payload

```
{
  "recordingsUrl": "https://transcribehm97c1.blob.core.windows.net/audio-files/2019-04-04_Blockchain%20explained%20with%20TruStory%27s%20Preethi%20Kasireddy.mp3?st=2019-05-27T12%3A19%3A27Z&se=2019-12-31T12%3A19%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=HFBvGl1pmCM95MNU9U3yniMNXrUMT6RmPb36F32cxrY%3D",
  "models": [],
  "locale": "en-US",
  "name": "I dont know why this is not working",
  "description": "Someone please send help",
  "properties": {
    "ProfanityFilterMode": "Masked",
    "PunctuationMode": "DictatedAndAutomatic"
  }
}
```

4. I get a “202 Accepted” response with below headers. This confirms that the request body is valid.

```
location: https://westus.cris.ai/api/speechtotext/v2.0/transcriptions/69b7abf4-6383-4490-88a9-9fd42a77e470
```

5. When I make a GET Request to the above location, I see this

```
{
  "recordingsUrl": "https://transcribehm97c1.blob.core.windows.net/audio-files/2019-04-04_Blockchain explained with TruStory's Preethi Kasireddy.mp3?st=2019-05-27T12:19:27Z&se=2019-12-31T12:19:00Z&sp=rl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=HFBvGl1pmCM95MNU9U3yniMNXrUMT6RmPb36F32cxrY%3D",
  "resultsUrls": {},
  "models": [“I have removed this for brevity”],
  "statusMessage": "The recordings URI is invalid.",
  "id": "69b7abf4-6383-4490-88a9-9fd42a77e470",
  "createdDateTime": "2019-05-27T12:43:39Z",
  "lastActionDateTime": "2019-05-27T12:43:50Z",
  "status": "Failed",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "name": "I dont know why this is not working",
  "description": "Someone please send help",
  "properties": {
    "ProfanityFilterMode": "Masked",
    "PunctuationMode": "DictatedAndAutomatic"
  }
}
```

6. The transcriptions fails for some URL's while passing for others for blobs in the same storage although they are all valid URL’s. **The SAS URI in the request is valid till end of the
   year.**
7. I have re-tried the same request multiple times via code and Postman and it fails.

**Link to Swagger Page** : https://westus.cris.ai/swagger/ui/index

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be due to the audio file size. Please refer the core features for [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-to-text) as the REST support only short Audio.

Comment: I can confirm that the space is not the problem. I have transcribed 50 other files that have spaces in their name.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two things that helped me create a SAS URL to feed into the Azure Speech Batch transcription service. I was frustratingly getting the "Authentication failed for recordings URI." message.

- When you navigate to a file through the storage interface, extra spaces will be hidden. For example, my file was named `Weekly  standup.mp4` (two spaces) but in the storage interface it appeared as `Weekly standup.mp4` (one space). It is best to fetch your blob name programmatically to then feed it to your downstream task rather than to copy it from the interface.
- When generating a SAS URL, also feed it a start date along with the expiry date :

```
    from azure.storage.blob import generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions
    from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

    sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
        account_name=account_name,
        account_key=account_key,
        container_name = container_name,
        blob_name = blob_name,
        permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
        start=datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=8),
        expiry=datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(hours=8)
    )
```